# Async Error FIx Needed with GeoCoder

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-geocoder

Don't understand how to fix this error in my code, "Method getText must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker more... (⌘F1)".

In this line, String name = addressEdit.getText().toString(); the portion "addressEdit.getText()" is underlined.

I've looked and found similar but the solutions are directly applicable.

CODE BELOW -

private class GeocodeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
        String errorMessage = "";

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Address doInBackground(Void... none) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        if (fetchType == USE_ADDRESS_NAME) {
            String name = addressEdit.getText().toString();
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(name, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorMessage = "Service not available";
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, e);
            }
        } else {
            errorMessage = "Unknown Type";
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        }

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
            return addresses.get(0);

        return null;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You are supposed to read/manipulate Views only from the UI thread. `doInBackground` executes in a background thread. Hence the error.

Comment: You could read the addressEdit text in your empty `onPreExecute()` method which runs on the UI thread